# Excel: How to auto-update & append new entries from sub-sheets into a main sheet

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with 5 tabs/sheets.

The first tab/sheet is a "Master" tab showing all our client entries. It is for viewing only - I never want to touch this tab.

The remaining four tabs/sheets are the same entries, but split by region (ei.. Neverland, Candyland, Wonderland, Park Place, Boardwalk). I want to be able to update the "region" sheets/tabs, so it will auto-update it's same entry in the main sheet - I know how to do this.

The issue is I ALSO want to be able to add new entries into these region tabs, and then have that auto-append the new entry to the main tab. As their are mutliple sheets linked to append, I don't want any sheets to over-write each other when appending either.

I am having trouble figuring out how to do both. I have very little coding experience. Is there a built in way to do this?

Comment: No, there is no such built-in functionality. Anyhow, this seems much more like a question of logic and not a question of coding. I'd guess that this is a question of DB logic asking for data modelling and thus your question is probably better suited for [DBA.StackExchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). BTW: updating the main sheet could be as easy as linking the `master` sheet to the other sheets with a simple `=SheetNeverland!A1`.... and your master sheet will be always up-to-date.

Comment: No, there is no out-of-the-box way, you'll either need to learn VBA or hire a VBA developer